# Проверить установку пакета

Tags: java, android

У меня есть приложение и в приложении есть игровые монеты, теперь я хочу сделать, чтоб по кнопке предлагалось установить другое приложение из маркета и после установки давались монеты, как все это можно проверить?

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Проверка на то, установлено ли приложение:

```
boolean installed = appInstalledOrNot("com.Example.kek");  

private boolean appIsInstalled(String uri) {
    PackageManager pm = getPackageManager();
    boolean app_installed;
    try {
        pm.getPackageInfo(uri, PackageManager.GET_ACTIVITIES);
        app_installed = true;
    }
    catch (PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e) {
        app_installed = false;
    }
    return app_installed;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Объявляете в манифесте ресивер:

```
<receiver android:name=".AppListener">
    <intent-filter android:priority="100">
         <action android:name="android.intent.action.PACKAGE_INSTALL"/>
         <action android:name="android.intent.action.PACKAGE_ADDED"/>  
         <action android:name="android.intent.action.PACKAGE_REMOVED"/>
         <data android:scheme="package"/> 
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

Точно не помню, но возможно нужны какие-то пермишены.

И создаете класс

```
public class AppListener extends BroadcastReceiver {

@Override 
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent arg1) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub 
    Log.v(TAG, "there is a broadcast");
    } 
}
```

Теперь в него будут приходить броадкасты об установке и удалении приложений.

Чтобы проверить, установлено ли приложение в данный момент:

```
PackageManager pm = context.getPackageManager();
try {
     ApplicationInfo appInfo = pm.getApplicationInfo("app.package.name", 0);
    //такое приложение есть
} catch (NameNotFoundException e) {
    //такого приложения нет
}
```